# Preventing instance of same function if loaded once jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My website navigation needs to be converted into vertical nav so i measure the width of the viewport and bind it with `resize` and `load` function.then it executes the `menuConvert()` function. But in resizing window it causes multiple execution of the `menuConvert()` function.

### My js codes are

```
$(window).bind('load resize', function(){
  width = $(window).width();
  console.log(width)
  if(width < 800){
     menuConverter(); // This is the function
  }
});
```

I want to prevent the execution of the function if it is once executed.Can any one help

Answer (score 4):

You can unbind event

```
$(window).bind('load resize', function(){
  width = $(window).width();
  console.log(width)
  if(width < 800){
     menuConverter(); // This is the function

     //Unbind
     $(window).unbind('load resize')
  }
});
```

I would recommend the use of [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) inplace of `.bind()` and `.unbind()` respectively.

Comment: This won't work if you expand the width above 800 and then go back to a smaller window. If you want to convert/unconvert you will have a problem. However, there is no unconvert function right now so maybe this is not an issue?

Comment: @Satpal thats good but if i resize the window to previous large screen? It doesn't go back as before

Comment: @SumaiyaSalam, What does `menuConverter()` exactly do?

Comment: @Satpal it actually make horizontal menu to vertical and add some markups .Nothing more than that

Comment: @SumaiyaSalam, So re-executing `menuConverter()` will solve the problem? right

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
var flag800;
$(window).bind('load resize', function () {
    if (width < 800) {
        if (flag800 !== true) {
            menuConverter(); // This is the function
            flag800 = true;
        }
    } else {
        flag800 = false;
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5fm0rqf0/)

Comment: thats good but if i resize the window to previous large screen? It doesn't go back as before

Comment: @SumaiyaSalam see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5fm0rqf0/2/ - if you want to run `menuConverter` every time once the switch happens

Answer (score 0):

use a simple bool variable.

```
var menexe = false;
$(window).bind('load resize', function(){

      width = $(window).width();
      console.log(width)
      if(width < 800){
            if(menexe === false){
         menuConverter(); // This is the function
         menexe = true;
         }
      }
    });
```

Comment: thats good but if i resize the window to previous large screen? It doesn't go back as before

Comment: you need to add another even that fires on every resize, and make menexe = false again.